# applying a change to multiple textures

Tags: materials, color

I have an object with about 20 different texture files, and I want to apply a change to all of them without having to go into each of them individually to do it. Is there a way for me to do this? All I want to do is change the base color.

Comment: Do you mean materials? What exactly do you want to change?

Comment: @scurest yes, the materials. i just want to change the base color from dark gray to a lighter shade, but there are like 20 different materials that i want to change the color of and i am wondering if there is a way to do it all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will change all the materials on the active object to have the same Base Color as the first material slot.

So first change the material in your first slot to have the Base Color you want, then open the Text Editor, paste this script, and hit Run.

```
import bpy
base_color = None
for slot in bpy.context.object.material_slots:
    if slot.material:
        if slot.material.node_tree:
            principled = next((
                n for n in slot.material.node_tree.nodes if n.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED'
            ), None)
            if principled:
                if not principled.inputs["Base Color"].links:
                    if not base_color:
                        base_color = principled.inputs["Base Color"].default_value
                    else:
                        principled.inputs["Base Color"].default_value = base_color
```

[image: Example showing all material slots changed to match the first]